# RxJava Single.error inside a map or flatMap

Tags: java, kotlin, exception, rx-java2

I haave this

```
private Single<Integer>(){

    Single.just(1,2,3).map{
      it
    }.onErrorResumeNext {
     Single.error(UserException("400", errorMessage))
    }
}
```

Now, I want to insert an extra object in my exception.

```
Single.just(1,2,3).map{
//anything
}.onErrorResumeNext {
  moreInformation.map{
     Single.error(UserException("400", errorMessage + it.message))
  }
}
```

I have an error, that I need return an `Single<Integer>` and not an `Single<UserExepction>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `onErrorReturn`

```
Flowable.just(1, 2, 3).map { x -> x }.onErrorReturn { 1 }
```